# Check for the image in an HTML document

Tags: javascript, html, .net, powershell

I am trying to automate a task of extracting some information from the HTML document and storing it in an excel file.
I am trying to identify all the rows with a red image in a cell.
the image is present in HTML as follows.

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAKIAAAAAAIAAAP+ZmW+MnP8A//8AAP///wACACH5BAEAAAQALAAAAAAQABAAAAOWSEREhEREREhERIRERERIRESERDQACAAAgAAAQ0ggIoIiIiIoAkSAUlVVaFZVgUAEUlhVZoFRFUBIIFWFZhFVWAFEgFJlZmhmVYFABFJYVWWGERVASCBVhWUWUVgBRIBSZmZoZlGBQARSWGZmgRERQEggVYUWEVFYAUSAERERGBERgUA0AAgAAIAAAENIRESERERESESUADs=" alt="Red rating">
```

I am writing the script in Powershell and below is the compare statement i have written

```
if($rows.getElementsByTagName("img") -match "Red rating")
```

also tried

```
if($rows.getElementByTagName("img").alt -eq "Red rating")
```

but it is not working.

```
function CreateExcelFromHtml($document, [string]$excelFile)
{   
    Write-Host "1"
    $excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application    
    $excel.Visible = $false # $true
    $excel.DisplayAlerts = $false
    $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Add()    
    $sheet = $workbook.ActiveSheet

    Write-Host "Filling in Excel file"
    $row = 1;
    # iterate over tables
    $tables = $document.getElementsByTagName("table")
    $captions = $document.getElementsByTagName("img")
    #$document.getElementsByTagName("caption")
    Write-Host "2"
    for($t=0; $t -lt $tables.length; $t++){

        # create 2 row space between tables
        $row += 2
        #Write here the code for thead.(table header)

        #iterate over rows
        $rows = $tables[$t].getElementsByTagName("tr") 
        for($i=0; $i -lt $rows.length; $i++)
        {

        if($rows.getElementsByTagName("img") -match "Red rating"){
            # iterate over cells

            $cells = $rows[$i].getElementsByClassName("sa-table-cell") 
            for($j=0; $j -lt $cells.length; $j++)
            {
                # load each cell contents into an excel cell
                $sheet.Cells.Item($row + $i, $j+1) = $cells[$j].innerText.Trim()
            }

        if($rows.getElementsByTagName("img") -match "Yellow rating"){
            # iterate over cells

            # create new sheet with yellow rating rows

        }

        # add corrective action column to first table
        if($t -eq 0){ 
            $j += 1 # increment table size
            $sheet.Cells.Item($row, $j) = "Corrective Action"; 
        }

        # get table title from corresponding caption
        $title = [string]$captions[$t].innerText

        StyleTable $sheet $title $row $i $j

        $row += $i

    }

    Write-Host "Formating Excel file"
    $sheet.UsedRange.ColumnWidth = 18

    Write-Host "Saving Excel file"
    $workbook.SaveAs($excelFile, 51)
    $workbook.Close();
    $excel.Quit()

}


Function StyleTable($sheet, $tableTitle, $startRow, $numberOfRows, $endColumn){

    # give the table a title and style it
    $titleCell = $sheet.Cells($startRow - 1, 1)
    $titleCell.Value = $tableTitle   
    $titleCell.Font.Name = "Cambria"
    $titleCell.Font.Size = 14
    $titleCell.Font.Bold = $true
    $titleCell.Font.ThemeColor = 5

    # give the table a border 
    $tableRange = $sheet.Range($sheet.Cells($startRow, 1), ` 
        $sheet.Cells($startRow + $numberOfRows - 1, $endColumn)) 

    $tableRange.Borders.Weight = 2

    # make the table header bold and blue
    $headerRange = $sheet.Range($sheet.Cells($startRow, 1), `
        $sheet.Cells($startRow, $endColumn))

    $headerRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 37
    $headerRange.Font.Bold = $true
}
```

Comment: That's only part of your code, how do you obtain $rows? What follows the if condition?

Comment: i have added the whole script, still there are a lot of changes to make but im struck  at the above mentioned point.